# Weird translation bug in theme - "SKU" can't be translated, but is a translateable string

Tags: magento2

I found out that there is one specific string in the core magento template base that somehow can't be translated.

In File `./vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/items.phtml` there is the heading "SKU":

```
 <th class="col sku"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('SKU') ?></th>
```

If one tries to translate it with inline translations: there is no field to add customized text.

If one tries to translate it with i18n-CSVs: no change at all.

Everything else is translateable, but just not this single piece of string. Why is this and how could one translate this anyway? We are experiencing this Bug with Magento 2.1.11.

Comment: have you tried with a language pack? if you check for example the italian language pack [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mageplaza/magento-2-italian-language-pack/master/it_IT.csv) you can see there is a line of translation for SKU in the magento_advancedchekout module... maybe you just need to set the correct module and theme in your translation file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like its a a bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13753

A short fix is:

1. duplicate the template into your theme/module
2. change "SKU" to "Article #" (closest approach I can imagine)
3. translate "Article #" to whatever you want
4. this will work